# Ruby: how to determine an object type in irb and binding.pry?

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I have just begun adding binding.pry after my objects in order to start determining what they evaluate to. However, now I want to know what type of object the output is.

How can I do this in irb? How can I do this in binding.pry?

EDIT:
Here is what I have tried to determine the type of object H. I know it is a hash, but sometimes it is less obvious in the console:

```
irb(main):001:0> H = Hash["a" => 100, "b" => 200]
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
irb(main):002:0> H
=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
irb(main):003:0> type(H)
NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for main:Object
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):004:0> object.class(H)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `object' for main:Object
Did you mean?  object_id
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):005:0> object.is_a?(H)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `object' for main:Object
Did you mean?  object_id
    from (irb):5
    from /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the `class` with

```
h = {a: 100, b: 200}
h.class

# Hash
```

You can also check if something is of a particular class

```
h.is_a? Hash
# true

h.is_a? String
# false
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That extra bit is really helpful for learning.

Comment: `class Foo < Hash; end Foo.new.is_a? Hash` #=> `true`. Moral: to `check if something is of a particular class` one should use `instance_of?` :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko but that also shows you that Foo responds to Hash methods so it's not all useless. You could also say `Foo < Hash` to check that Foo inherits from Hash.

Comment: @maxple never implied that `is_a?` useless. Just wanted to emphasise, that if one wants to check object's type strictly, only `instance_of` would do, whereas `kind_of?` and `is_a?` won't :)

Comment: This doesn't show the type, it shows the class, which is something completely different.

Comment: You're right, I make no mention of type in my answer. But this is the closest to what the op is asking for. Whether type actually exists in the language itself or 'in the mind of the programmer' I find is a more of a philosophical question, not a very practical one.

Answer (score -1):

The Ruby Language has no concept of "type". Or, to be more precise: in Ruby, types only exist latently in the mind of the programmer, they are not manifest in the program. Ergo, there is no way to get an object's type from the program, you can only get it from the programmer.

Sometimes, types are written down in the documentation or in comments. Some types are basically community folklore, not written down anywhere but passed down from generation to generation.

You can ask an object about its [class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-class), you can ask it about its [methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-methods), you can ask it [whether it responds to a specific message](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F), but you can not ask it about its type.

Note that older versions of Ruby had a [`type`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-type) but that method was removed because it was misleading: it didn't actually return the type (I explained above why that is impossible), it returned the *class*, which is something completely different.

Comment: Interesting, so that explains this response `pry(#<Integrations::YoutubeController>)> daily_youtube_stats.class
=> IntegrationStatistic(id: integer, credentials_id: integer, followers_count: integer, follows_count: integer, views_count: integer, likes_count: integer, dislikes_count: integer, comments_count: integer, shares_count: integer, media_count: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, integration_id: integer)`